# I want to activate a remote shock collar based on messages in a discord server

Tags: arduino

So, for starters - this is a kink thing and not an animal abuse thing. I have an introductory understanding of electrical engineering (the most complex thing I've done is make an oscilloscope from an old camp TV) so I'm confident i could create the hardware, but the code side is completely greek to me.

Like I don't even know what kind of board (Arduino?) I would use.

Comment: easiest way would be to get a remote control dog collar and hack the remote control ... that way you can test the collar on yourself before you do any mod .... you may wish to edit your post ... `I've heard arduino? ` is a silly question to be asking us ... in fact `help?` is not a very good question either

Comment: Do you already know which collar you want to use?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* madeline69, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an interesting project, but in the current form it's too broad for this board.

This could be a path to follow, if you run into problems, just ask here, but make sure that it's a closed question that deals with a single problem ("How can I simulate a button press on a remote with my ESP32- Arduino"):

I found this: [discord-arduino-simplest](https://github.com/DedaDev/discord-arduino-simplest) which is a chatbot that runs on an arduino and turns an led on or off depending on messages in the discord-server.

Other projects:
[send discord-message on wifi-arduino](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/labsud/send-a-message-on-discord-f216e0)

Board wise: the [Adafruit HUZZAH32 – ESP32 Feather Board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2821) is a good starting point. It has wifi and a battery-connector so you could add it with a small LiPo to the collar. Should be the size of a matchbox.

As you have experience with electronics, you should be able to analyse the receiver on the shock collar. I guess it only sends a signal to the shock-generator which you can also to with the arduino. If you do it right, the normal remote will still work.